# How do you put 'weight' on different conditions in php while also keeping your results semi-random?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm

I am making an advertisement network and I want to display ads that have the highest CPM (very important) and the oldest dates (less important). But, if I do this, I will get the same ads all the time, so I want to add some randomness into the equation too.

So I want to make an algorithm that adds some weight do the 2 conditions while also keeping it semi-random. I have no clue where to even start and I haven't been able to find anything to help me. I would appreciate it if you could leave an answer or refer me to something that can help.

Thanks

Comment: Please improve this question to not make it so vague. Let us narrow in on something

Comment: you can observe this, I think it may help clarify your algorithm
http://stackoverflow.com/q/497116/6570921

Comment: @Drew I want to display an ad from the database based on cpm, age and also make it semi-random.

Comment: In the meantime, See **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you :p

Comment: This is a good question in my opinion. If you need help further (implementing this in mysql), ask  Nico below, or anyone else that answers, for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need randomness with some well-defined probability distribution, you will probably need all ads in memory. I assume, this is not feasible in your application, so I will focus on an alternative approximation. But I'll come back to that at the end of this question.

### Approximation

The central aspect is that you need a single importance value that combines any number of attributes. In your case, this could be something as the following:

```
I = weight_cpm * cpm / max_cpm + weight_age * age / max_age
```

The maximum values are used to normalize the two scales to each other and could also be left away. The weights specify the relative importance of each attribute.

So you could sort your ads with respect to this importance value and take the k-th ad, where `k` is a random number.

### Specific Probability Distribution

If you want to specify a probability distribution, you would need to specify a frequency to each ad. This could be its importance divided by the sum of all ad importances. Doing this, you ensure that your frequencies sum to 1.

What you need to do then is to define an arbitrary order of the ads and stack their frequency values. For example, if you have frequencies `0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3`, you would stack them as follows:

```
0.1  |  0.1  |     0.5       |  0.3      |
-------------------------------------------
0   0.1     0.2             0.7         1.0
Ad1     Ad2        Ad3            Ad4
```

All you need to do then is to generate a random number between 0 and 1 and choose the ad in whose interval the random number falls. E.g. if your random number is 0.6, you'd choose Ad3.

### Hybrid

If you need a bit of both, you can do some hybrid approach. I.e. retrieve the top `n` ads with respect to their importance and define the probability distribution on this subset.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful answer. But, how would I go about executing this? Would i (importance) be stored in the database and need to be updated every day as it ages?

Comment: No, you can just let the database calculate it on the fly. E.g. `SELECT cpm + age AS Importance From ...`

Comment: I was thinking about just using cpm and not age. Would this be how I would do it? "SELECT (cpm/SUM(cpm)) AS Importance FROM ads" and add all values to an array and find a random one.

Comment: That depends on the specific database. But I guess you would need a subquery for the sum. You could do this as well in client code.

Comment: Ok can you help me with this query.

Comment: `$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ad_id, (cpm/SUM(cpm)) AS Importance FROM `ads`")){
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ad_id, $Importance);

        while($stmt->fetch()){
         for($x=0;$x<=round($Importance*100)){
          $allads[] = $ad_id;
         }
        }`

Comment: I only works for the first row and stops there. I removed the whole (cpm/SUM(cpm)) AS Importance and the while looped worked

Comment: As I said, you need a subquery: `SELECT ad_id, (cpm/(SELECT SUM(cpm) FROM ads)) AS Importance FROM ads`